# How do i change a label to match the selected index of a combo box?

Tags: c#

Here i have some code that works fine. Except the thing i need it do the most right now.

I have a label which i've named (**lblProfileID**) and i need this label to display the (**ProfileID**) that matches the (**ProfileName**) depending on the **selection** i've made in the **combobox** where all the Profilenames are stored.

How do i accomplish this task?

```
       public void QueriesProfile()
    {
        QueryResult queryResultProfile = null;
        String SOQL = "";
        SOQL = "Select Id, Name from Profile";
        queryResultProfile = Sfdcbinding.query(SOQL);

        string profileID = null;
        string ProfileName = null;

        if (queryResultProfile.size > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < queryResultProfile.size; i++)
            {
                Profile userProfile = (Profile)queryResultProfile.records[i];
                profileID = userProfile.Id;
                ProfileName = userProfile.Name;

                string[] uSersProfile = { ProfileName, profileID };
                listProfile.AddRange(uSersProfile);
                cmbProfile.Items.Add(ProfileName);

                lblProfileID.Text = cmbProfile.SelectedIndex(profileID); /// <--- How do i do this?
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming your talking about the Label controller object, there is no .Text property, there's a .Content property which you can assign a string value. Aside from that you can convert your collection to an IEnumerable<whatever type> and use a Linq .Where() to find the desired data.

Comment: What type of application are you targeting ? WPF ? WinForm, ASP.Net ?

Comment: register to the SelectedIndexChange of the combobox and then change the label text

Comment: @Tomer Klein Anyway you can give me some example code? because i dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 public void QueriesProfile()
    {
      cmbProfile.SelectedIndexChanged+=cmbProfile_SelectedIndexChanged;  
      QueryResult queryResultProfile = null;
        String SOQL = "";
        SOQL = "Select Id, Name from Profile";
        queryResultProfile = Sfdcbinding.query(SOQL);

        string profileID = null;
        string ProfileName = null;

        if (queryResultProfile.size > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < queryResultProfile.size; i++)
            {
                Profile userProfile = (Profile)queryResultProfile.records[i];
                profileID = userProfile.Id;
                ProfileName = userProfile.Name;

                string[] uSersProfile = { ProfileName, profileID };
                listProfile.AddRange(uSersProfile);
                cmbProfile.Items.Add(ProfileName);

              
              
                
            }
        }
    }


 private void cmbProfile_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
lblProfileID.Text = cmbProfile.SelectedIndex(profileID);
        }
```

Comment: That doesnt work, because ".SelectedIndex" can't be used like a method. it's a property.